# Finding the nth to last node in a single linked list using recursion

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion, linked-list

I know this question has been asked already but I would like to solve it using recursion. Each node in the list contains an integer value (int val). I would like to return the integer value, not just print it. I came up with the following:

```
int findKthNode (node* head, int n){
    if(!head)
        return 1;
    int retval = findkthNode(head->next, n);
    if(retval==n)
        return head->val;
    return 1+retval;
}
```

Once I reach the end of the list, I return 1. After that I add 1 to the previous return value until I reach the nth node from the end. At that point I return the int value at that node. There is one problem with this approach. I continue to add 1 until I return back to the first call. So if my list was 1,5,10,20,40,80,100, I would end up returning 85 for n=2, instead of 80 since I would add 1 five more times before returning. How would I fix this?

Also, I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way to return a pointer to the nth last node using recursion. I can't see a way to do this with a singly linked list.

Comment: And what should happen if there aren't at least `n` values in the list?

Comment: @JimMischel Good Point. Currently, my function would just return 1 plus the number of items in the list, which is not necessarily a bad thing. It would be better if I changed it to return -1 or the number of items in the list.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724339/efficiently-finding-nth-from-last-element-in-a-linked-list/40724340?noredirect=1#comment68683709_40724340

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the same variable for two different things, use two different variables.  Pass an integer by reference to keep track of how many nodes from the end you are, and use the return for the result.

```
node* findKthNode (node* head, int find, int& found){
    if(!head) {
        found = 1;
        return head;
    }
    node* retval = findkthNode(head->next, find, found);
    if(found==find)
        retval = head;
    found = found + 1;
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. You accidentally typed int find instead of int n for the parameters. Why do you say found==n+1? If n was 2, wouldn't this return the 3rd last element, unless that's what you intended.

Comment: I changed `n` to `find` so I could remember which variable was which.  I had that code because I thought yours was wrong, but then realized it reverses when `head` is `NULL`, not `head->next`.  Yours was right and I corrected mine accordingly.

Comment: why do you return null if (!head), can you return head?

Comment: @John: You're right, that was an error in the code that it couldn't find the last element.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

The following will return a pointer to the nth from last node, or `NULL` if there aren't enough nodes.

```
node* findKthNode(node* head, int n)
{
    node* rslt = NULL;
    doFind(head, n, &rslt);
    return rslt;
}

int doFind(node* head, int n, node** rslt)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int ret = doFind(head->next, n, rslt);
    if (ret == n)
    {
        *rslt = head;
    }
    return ret + 1;
}
```

In this case, `n` is 0-based. To find the item at the end of the list, you would write:

```
node* rslt = findKthNode(head, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was needlessly making the problem more difficult for myself by using a limited number of function parameters and temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need two "return values". One for the values to return and one for the returned depth.
I would add a `int* depth` parameter to the method signature to "return" the depth.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was trying to do too much with a single variable.