# Efficiently finding nth from last element in a linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

What is an efficient way of finding nth from last element in a singly/doubly linked list?

Comment: This seems fairly pointless, there is no way to do better than the trivial way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient way of finding nth from last element in a linked list.

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int getNthFromLast(struct Node *head, int n){
    struct Node *curr = head;
    struct Node *nthFromLast=NULL;
    int count=0;
    int value=-1;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        count++;
        curr=curr->next;
        if(count==n){
            nthFromLast=head;
        }else
            if(count>n){
                nthFromLast=nthFromLast->next;
            }
    }
    if(count>=n){
        value=nthFromLast->data;
    }
    return value;
}
```

This example has been written in C++ and can be replicated similarly in other languages. The method is passed a pointer to the first node of the linked list and the index from last element, whose data it returns. If the position is not present, the method returns -1.

Similar approach can be taken in case of a doubly linked list as well as circular linked list.

**EDIT: In case of a doubly linked list, just move n items in reverse. Totally forgot about that. Credits: Jim Mischel**

Comment: With a doubly linked list all you have to do is count `n` nodes backwards from the end. Note also that this isn't fundamentally any more or less efficient than making a full scan of the list to find the count, and then starting over at the head and moving forward `(count-n)` times.

Comment: Agreed on the doubly linked list point, kind of forgot to take that into account. Thanks for highlighting that. Will edit. Although, if you find the count first `(loop 1)` and then move forward `(count-n)` times, wouldn't you be executing the second loop of `(count - n)` length in vain? If, say the value of n is on the smaller side, then you would actually have to traverse more than half of the list without any meaningful gain. So I guess that's where pointer number two comes into play, which tracks the location of the `(count-n)` th item.

Comment: Yes, but if you're doing it with two passes you're only incrementing one pointer in the loop. In your version, you end up doing `count + (count-n)` pointer increments in a single pass. In the two-pass version, you do `count` increments in one pass, and `(count-n)` increments in the second pass. The amount of work done is the same either way.

Comment: True. Although, using a single loop for all the computation seemed cleaner since it involved only a single traversal.